# VBA Internet Explorer Download

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vba, excel, httprequest

First of all, I want to say that stackoverflow has helped me a GREAT deal with my current project, so thanks! But I have hit a point where I can no longer find help by skimming through previous questions. First, a little overview of what I'm doing.

At my job we have this extremely tedious process that we perform regularly, and I really want to automate it. The process is very basic, we go to a website, log-in, navigate to the appropriate page, copy and paste 6 values from excel into a form on the website, submit the form and download a specific output report. We repeat the process 60 times so this seemed like a prime candidate for Excel-Internet Explorer automation.

I built a pretty basic Excel Macro that can open up a new window with the appropriate URL, log-in, navigate to the correct page, fill in the form and submit the form, but I cannot figure out how to download the report. There is some added complexity to this, and I am just not familiar enough with Javascript, PHP ect. to figure out what is going on.

Problem: when I choose the correct report to generate, a new window pops-up with the generated report. This page is essentially empty when I click "View Source Document." There is a link to a Javascript page in the header, there is a little bit of CSS directly in the page, and like two tiny snippets of HTML. There is a download button on this page, but it doesn't look like it's being created in HTML.

QUESTION 1: Is this a Javascript application? Is there a way for me to simulate pressing the download button?

From what I understand, the complexity of my macro will increase substantially if I have to navigate between two IE windows, (not to mention there isn't an HTML link for me to click to download the spreadsheet) so I started to try and figure out a different way to do this. I looked at the URL of the new window with the generated report, and tried to analyze what was happening with Firefox's Developer tools (specifically Web Console). Here's where I get even more lost...

There are a series of "POSTS". These POSTS show up when the output is being created within the website:

```
POST https://www.website.com/somethingdb/quickframe/prod/#####/single_frame_results/correct_output.asp?THIS_KEY=370120c59da884dbdc375b1582a2142c1363533393a313335363032353737363a3646314a313937334a32353030303&bEmbedded=1

POST https://www.website.com/somethingdb/javascriptsource/prod/#####/website/forms/datagrid/DataGrid.html

POST https://www.website.com/qc?function=QuickFrameRmi
```

Then when I click the Download button, One POST and one GET show up:

```
POST https://www.website.com/qc?function=CorrectReport.generateExportFile
```

GET

```
GET https://www.website.com/somethingdb/quickframe/prod/#####/dlf/x6::370120c59da884dbdc375b1582a2142c1363533393a313335363032353737363a3646314a313937334a323530303031356026339.xls/sfn/RIGHTPAGE_scen_1_deal_cf.xls
```

The referrer for the GET looks like this:

```
https://www.website.com/somethingdb/quickframe/prod/#####/single_frame_results/correct_output.asp?THIS_KEY=370120c59da884dbdc375b1582a2142c1363533393a313335363032353737363a3646314a313937334a32353030303&sPagename=RIGHTPAGE&nScenarios=1&bShowExtendedFields=1&bShowAllCollats=0&ShowUnderlyingPage=0&sUnderlyingPage=&WebsitewrapDb=websitewrap&iSettleId=&bScrollbars=true&time=1356025839577
```

Like I said, my knowledge of these things is very limited but I do know that once I click on the download button, the GET from above is an actual file name that is stored on the website’s server. I can go into Excel, click on “Open” and put that file path in and it will download EXACTLY what I need.

So here is what I am thinking. If I could tell the website to simulate the download process, and log what that GET is, then I could just store that away, and when the Macro finishes generating all of the reports I need, it can just navigate back into Excel and set up a simple Loop to download all of them?? I have identified the portions of the GET that change:

```
x6::370120c59da884dbdc375b1582a2142c

63032353737363a3646314

6026339
```

This is my first post, so I apologize if I was too long winded in my back-story. Just wanted to be as clear as possible from the get go. I am wondering what is truly happening inside the website? Is what I am suggesting making sense? Is it possible? Is there a better way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing pricing data uploads :) Check this out: [export-and-import-from-excel-into-a-web-page](http://www.outsystems.com/how-to/import-data-from-excel-file/) . I have seen `pricelink` uses their own Excel sheets to do similar.

Comment: Yes, this can be automated in Excel. I have similar experience before.  If I am understanding you correctly, what you mean is : You need to first LOGIN <--- By HTTP Authentication or  authentication system on the website?
Then click the download button , it will generate a GET request.
But different file will have different GET para.

It would be best if you can give us the website or else you need some basic knowledge in JavaScript to find out how the GET params. are generated